# Adding additional checkbox under Forms Settings tab

Tags: sitecore-forms

I need to add additional checkbox under Forms Settings tab.

How can I customize it?

[image]

Comment: @Peter Procházka we can not override UpdateItem and InitializeModel method as these methods are not virtual, it seems to me there is limitation from Sitecore.

Answer (score 5):

### 1. First step is to create new item under PageSettings for FormSettings in `core` database.

You need to add it in `core` database under `/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/FormSettingsPropertyGrid/PageSettings/SettingsForm` item:

[image]

It needs to be created based on `FormCheckBox Parameters` template.

Exact path to that template:

/sitecore/client/Business Component Library/version 2/Layouts/Renderings/Forms/Form/Templates/FormCheckBox Parameters

or you can find it based on its ID also:

{AD75C314-F983-4C56-81D5-DC10D5CCF4EF}

You need to also enable this new control in ControlDefinitions field in parent item that is based on FormSection template. This needs to be done in order to  render control under that form section:

[image]

There is already checkbox that you can use as starting point.
Make your checkbox based on this item:

/sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/FormSettingsPropertyGrid/PageSettings/SettingsForm/Advanced/PerformanceTracking

[image]

### 2. Second step is to add new field on Form template itself.

You can do this but altering item template under this path `/sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Form` and adding your custom shared checkbox field:

[image]

You will refer to this field name in next step shortly.

I would recommend creating your own Form template based on OOTB one located under the path - /sitecore/templates/System/Forms/Form and reference your newly created one but the reference is on so many places that it would be hard to do so.

### 3. Third step is to add your newly created setting in FormsViewModel.

For that you would need to create your own model class in your solution that will inherit Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.FormViewModel class.
It is located in Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.dll.

You need to add new property of type bool or string depending your requirements:

[image]

Reference your field created in step 2 here as `Fields["Your_Custom_field_name"]`.

You also need to set your fields value in UpdateItem method:

[image]

and InitializeModel method to get current value of your custom parameter:

[image]

### 4. Forth step is to alter Model class that will be used by Sitecore Forms.

Instead of OOTB Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.FormViewModel,Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc class you need to change Model Type field in Form item in `master` database in path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Forms/Field Types/Form` to your custom class created in step 3.

[image]

### 5. Last step is to create your own FormRenderingContext and make Sitecore Forms use it instead of OOTB one.

You need to inherit from Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.FormRenderingContext class and add properties around your custom property.

Create patch config file to change this serviceType to your custom class at the end.

From:

```
<register serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.IFormRenderingContext,
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc" 
implementationType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.FormRenderingContext, 
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc" lifetime="Transient" />
```

To:

```
<register serviceType="Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.IFormRenderingContext, 
Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc" implementationType="YouCustomImplementationClass, 
YourAssembly" lifetime="Transient" />
```

Comment: i duplicated the IsAjax item and renamed it , also updated few fields to change the text. However i could not see that new item. I cleared the cache too. Any idea , what i am missing ?

Comment: I need to select this newly added item at item - /sitecore/client/Applications/FormsBuilder/Components/Layouts/FormSettingsPropertyGrid/PageSettings/SettingsForm/Advanced

Comment: I was just about to update answer with this information. Will do so in a second. Was creating screenshots...

Comment: The checkbox is coming but after saving the form again its get deselected.  The checkbox is always unchecked after saving form. Any idea ?

Comment: @siddharth Answer updated with more steps. Please check and give me feedback.

Comment: if i select Ajax or Performace tracking check boxes under setting tab of form , i can see those values are reflecting to that form item under content tree on field Is Ajax and Is Tracing enabled checkbox. Further more these two fields are part of form template (Setting section). So i am just wondering how this is interlinked , selecting and deselecting from setting tab reflects under content tree.

Comment: Added second step @siddharth that I have missed to alter original Form template and add field there so it is persistent.

Comment: i had added field in Forms template, i am stuck at "You need to inherit from Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.FormRenderingContext class and add properties around your custom property." which is not clear to me.

Comment: I could not see any other property for reference in FormRenderingContext class

Comment: public class XYZ : FormRenderingContext
    {
     // declared all the variables
        public XYZ(IFieldNamingProvider fieldNamingProvider,
            IQueryStringProvider queryStringProvider, IFormStateProvider formStateProvider,
            IFormStoredDataProvider formStoredDataProvider, IFormEventsTracker formEventsTracker) : base(fieldNamingProvider, queryStringProvider, formStateProvider, formStoredDataProvider, formEventsTracker)
        {this._fieldNamingProvider = fieldNamingProvider;
            // remaining field set here 
       }   public bool SFMC { get; set; }
    }

Comment: could you confirm above comment text you are expecting as part of step 5

Comment: exactly @siddharth ;)

Comment: I tried @Peter Prochazka its not working this way :(

Comment: i checked in the fiddler, every time its sending false value of customized field on saving the form.

Comment: I followed the same steps mentioned above, but not able to apply/save the settings. Also found that  Form.cshtml model type is @model Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.FormViewModel, whereas we have our own model now.

Comment: public class ExtendedFormsViewModel: FormViewModel
    {
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        new public void InitializeModel(Item item)
        {
            base.InitializeModel(item);
            this.ErrorMessage = item.Fields["ErrorMessage"].ToString();
        }
        new public bool UpdateItem(Item item)
        {
            var result = base.UpdateItem(item);
            if(result)
            {
                item.Fields["ErrorMessage"]?.SetValue(ErrorMessage, false);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }